# in a React App, JSON.Stringify shows only first ltem and a length item instead of other items

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, web

In a React App, I have an array that want to convert it to JSON and send it to the server. I do it with this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(mainArray))
```

And I want to test it and I expect something like this to see:

```
"breakfast": {
                "1": "item 1",
                "2": "item 2"
            }
```

But I see only first item and a length item like this:

```
"breakfast": {
                "1": "item 1",
                "length": 2
            }
```

Also when I log the array without JSON.Stringify, I see something like this:

[image]

What's that **proto** ? Why I dont see my whole data in a clean way? Also in this situation, Every thing works fine if I do this:

```
console.lo(breakfast[0]) //prints first item
console.lo(breakfast[1]) //prints second item
```

First I thought its console.log's display problem, But when I send it to the server I get the same. I have just a simple array and I want to see it regularly.

Comment: can you show us where you declare mainArray?

Comment: I didn't post here because of complexity of code. mainArray is a value in Context as a global variable. what is your guess? it can be related to where is mainArray? as I say I can fetch all children with breakfast[0] etc. All data is present

Comment: I think your mainArray is actually an object which wasn't constructed correctly, that's why it looks so strange. Index based access works on objects as well (that's why it works for you to access breakfast[0] or [1])

Comment: `breakfast` as JSON is not an array: `breakfast: {` if it was an array it would show `breakfast: [`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something feels off about the initialization of `mainArray`/`breakfast`.

I tried to reproduce it, and if you paste this in your Chrome console you get a very similar output to yours, which indicates that it's indeed a mix of keys and objects that the console doesn't handle properly.

```js
const mainArray = {
  '1': 'item 1',
  length: 2
};
mainArray.__proto__ = ['item 2'];
console.log(mainArray);
```

[image]